How to write references in LaTeX in APA6 format and make formatting adjustments
I want the word and to be used instead of the symbol & when there is more than one author in the publication when placing the citation call-out within the text.
And, for entries of type @article, the name of the journal on the references page should be in bold instead of in italics.
For your information, these are the packages that I use
\begin{filecontents}{bibtexlogo.sty}
\def\lowBibTeX{{\reset@font\rmfamily B\kern-.05em%
    \raise.0ex\hbox{\scshape i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em%
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\def\BibTeX{\protect\lowBibTeX}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 right=15mm,
 bottom=15mm,
 }

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
%%%\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\newaliascnt{eqfloat}{equation}
\newfloat{eqfloat}{h}{eqflts}
\floatname{eqfloat}{Equation}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{%%%amsmath,
   %%%amsfonts, % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
   amssymb,amsthm}
%%%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} % doesn't work with 'apacite' bib style

\begin{document}

% cite some entries

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{refrans/ref}

\end{document}


I've taken the liberty of editing your posting (a) to edit the title to clarify your formatting objective, (b) to change some of the tags, and (c) to comment out two packages (cite and natbib) that you should definitely not be loading if your objective is to create formatted bibliographic entries that conform to APA -- more precisely, APA6 -- guidelines. Feel free to revert if you believe I misunderstood your intentions.

By loading the apacite citation management package and the apacite bibliography style, you should be getting the bibliographic references and citation call-outs formatted according to APA6 guidelines automatically. If you need to adhere to APA7 guidelines instead of APA6 guidelines, you'll need to change the entire setup. There are several postings on this site that describe how this setup change can/should be undertaken.

Please clarify the use case for wanting to make the two changes you mention. For all intents and purposes, you can no longer claim that you adhere to APA6 guidelines if you make these changes.

@Mico I am writing a master's thesis. The university's rules require using APA with the addition of the modifications that I have added to the question.

Unfortunately, those responsible, not only at universities, often tend to call something APA style, which is no longer APA, but ultimately some kind of author-year style. Even the term APA is rather imprecise, as there are significant differences between the various versions. For APA7 I would recommend biblatex with biblatex-apa. For more than minor deviations from both APA6 and APA7 I would recommend an author-year style of biblatex-ext, if no conforming style exists yet.

AFAIK for and instead of & you can redefine \BBAA or \BAnd (depending, where you want to change it). See section 6.1 of the apacite manual. For your problem with the journal title, I would need a MWEB.

This solved the problem I faced, as this code arranges the references alphabetically according to the last name, puts the Journal Name in bold, and indicates the reference in the text through (author's name, year of publication).
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, citestyle=authoryear, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

% Customizing the journal title to be bold instead of italic
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{\textbf{#1}}

% Adding a space between author and year in citations
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

% Removing the default bibliography title
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {},
}

% Adding the references file
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a sample text citing a source \parencite{Author2023}.

\newpage
\begin{center}
    \textbf{References}
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm} % Adding space below the References title

\printbibliography[heading=none] % Prevents biblatex from adding its own heading

\end{document}

